# IBM generate bearer token from Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-iam

I need help. You need a "Bearer Token" to call functions, but unfortunately I can't find instructions on how to generate it from Watson Assistant.
Would anyone please have a guide or an example?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where do you want to invoke a Cloud Function action? Are you aware of the instructions from https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks#dialog-webhooks-dialog-node-callout ?

Comment: I cannot use webhook, because I want use more than 1 IBM cloud Function and in Watson is possible use only 1 webhook for 1 assistant

Comment: Still you could use webhook. I implemented a "dispatch" webhook which then calls out to the right functions and REST APIs. The webhook is a Cloud Functions action.